# How to stop sourcemaps/usemin from appending css .map <link> tag to output?

Tags: gulp, source-maps, grunt-usemin, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-usemin

gulp-usemin is generating and appending css sourcemap link tag to output html, but not doing for js. How do I stop it from appending the sourcemap tag?

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    return gulp.src('templates/**')
        .pipe(usemin({
             css: [sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }), 'concat', cleanCss(), rev(), sourcemaps.write('./')],
             js: [sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }), 'concat', uglify(), rev(), sourcemaps.write('./')]
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Source HTML:

```
<!-- build:css css/style.min.css -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/script.min.js -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And this is the result output. Notice the extra sourcemap css link tag, but there is no respective sourcemap script tag for JS maps. Why is so and how do I stop inserting sourcemap tag for css??

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-cd92eb4ce7.min.css.map" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-cd92eb4ce7.min.css" media="screen"/>

<script src="js/script-602bf332b2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `gulp-usemin` you can see why this works for JS but not for CSS. `gulp-usemin` [explicitly makes sure](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/blob/a220139afe2cc16539e585692f847e5aea66f3ae/lib/htmlBuilder.js#L61) to only create `<script>` tags for files that end in `.js`. There is [no such check](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/blob/a220139afe2cc16539e585692f847e5aea66f3ae/lib/htmlBuilder.js#L69) for CSS.

This might be an oversight on the part of the `gulp-usemin` maintainers, so you should make sure to let them know on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/issues).

In case you have absolutely no other option and the issue is not fixed in `gulp-usemin` itself, here's a workaround:

```
var through = require('through2').obj;
var path = require('path');

var writeAndRemoveSourceMaps = through(function(file, enc, cb) {
  if (path.extname(file.path) == '.map') {
    gulp.dest('public').write(file, enc, cb);
    return;
  }
  this.push(file);
  cb();
});

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return gulp.src('templates/**')
    .pipe(usemin({
         css: [
           sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }),
           'concat',
           cleanCss(), 
           rev(), 
           sourcemaps.write('./'),
           writeAndRemoveSourceMaps  // FINAL STAGE IN PIPELINE
         ],
         js: [
           sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }), 
           'concat', 
           uglify(), 
           rev(), 
           sourcemaps.write('./')
         ]
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

The above adds another processing stage `writeAndRemoveSourceMaps` to the `css` pipeline, right after `sourcemaps.write()` has pushed the `.map` file to the stream. This stage manually writes the `.map` file to the destination directory and then removes it from the stream again, so that it can't reach `gulp-usemin` and no `<link>` tag for it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sven's answer I was able to file an issue, and the maintainer released a fix via [this commit](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin/commit/e873efbc3672141f13b0927d45352f24b044bf16)  almost immediately. The problem is no longer present as of `v.0.3.25`.